# group_by one attribute and map another attribute?

Tags: ruby

I have a list of objects with attributes A and B. Is there a one-liner way to store B values in arrays grouped by A values, in one loop? (not group_by, and then map) I'd have, as a result, an array of arrays.

```
result[a1] = [b1, b4, b5]
```

Edit : apparently i wasn't clear enough, sorry.
I have a list of objects like this :

```
class MyObject
  attr_accessor :attrA, :attrB
end
```

and i'd like a method that takes a list of MyObjects and returns all the attrB values grouped by attrA values.

Kristjan answer is good, and if there are no one liner doing this, it will be the accepted answer

Comment: It's better to use simple code example to help describe the problem.

Comment: Please supply some form of input/output specifications so that we can better assist in this matter. Also why not `group_by and then map this can still be a 1 liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a two-liner ok? Set up a results hash with a default empty array value, then loop through your items concatenating the value you want into the group you want.

```
list = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['a', 3],
  ['b', 4]
]

result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
list.each do |item|
  result[item.first] << item.last
end
puts result.inspect
# {"a"=>[1, 3], "b"=>[2, 4]}
```

Comment: You need to change `key` to `group` or vice-versa. it's more idiomatic to write `list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |(key, value),result| result[key] << value }`.

Comment: You could make this a 1 liner using `Enumerable#each_with_object` e.g. `list.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) {|a,h| h[a.a] << a.b }`

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch, and I updated it to make `item` look more like some arbitrary object. I like the one-lineiness of an `each_with_object` solution, but also find it somewhat less readable, so I'll leave it for code golfing :)